# How to resolve `No method with selector is implemented in this translation unit`?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got this error like the image below.

[image]

the `showSingerInfo` method is defined in parent class.

How can I resolve this warning??

Comment: What do you mean by `self` will find it on run time? If I am not wrong `showSingerInfo:` needs to be defined in the same class.

Comment: - (IBAction)ShowSingerInfo:(id)sender
{
  
} Declare method like this

Comment: call the method directly and Xcode will suggest the fix.

Comment: `showSingerInfo:` this method is defined in it's parent class.@raurora

Comment: call the method directly is ok, no warning.@BryanChen

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code into questions. You should copy and paste the code and then format it as code. Easier to read and then it's possible to search for it too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Clang is unable to resolve the declaration of the showSingerInfo: method.

I'm guessing that showSingerInfo: is a local method within the translation unit/class?  If so try either of the following.

1. Add the method declaration to your class header file.
2. If you do not want to publicly expose the method declaration then create a local/private category in your class implementation file and declare it there.